# Need solution to archive a folder excluding all .log and .err files using wildcards

Tags: tar, aix, compression, archive

I wish to archive all files and folders under `/app/jboss` while excluding all *.log* and *.err* files. The directory structure under `/app/jboss` is too vast and complex.

Thus a few sample files below should be excluded.

```
/app/jboss/standalone/server4/server1.log 
/app/jboss/standalone/server7/server1.log_bkp
/app/jboss/audir/diag.log
/app/jboss/standalone/server7/server1.err.gz
/app/jboss/standalone/version1.err
.... etc
```

I want my solution to work on AiX, Solaris & Linux if possible. Else, different solutions for each.

The best possible compression for me has been `.gz` which is what I prefer.

Tried Johan's solution below but it does not seem to work.

```
[root@myhost moht_bkp]# find /app/jboss -not -name "*.log*" | cpio -o | gzip > /app/moht_bkp/test.gz
 1360843 blocks 

[root@myhost moht_bkp]# echo $? 0  

[root@myhost moht_bkp]# ls -ltr 
total 
1097768 -rw-r--r-- 1 root      root      562056007 Jul 20 10:45 test.gz   

[root@myhost moht_bkp]# gunzip test.gz 

[root@myhost moht_bkp]# ls -ltr total 680424 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 696751616 Jul 20 16:34 test
```

Comment: Archive as a single archive or as separate files?

Comment: Need a single archive that should have `jboss` folder and its contents @Artem S. Tashkinov.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/302439/tar-exclude-certain-files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of find, cpio, and gzip to achieve this. Cpio in copy-out mode takes a list of files from standard input and creates an archive on standard output. The archive can be passed to gzip for compression.

The following example finds all files except the ones with extension .err and .log, and passes the file list to cpio, which in turn passes the archive to gzip. Finally the compressed archive is redirected to a file.

```
find app/jboss -not -name "*.err" -not -name "*.log" | cpio -o | gzip > /tmp/backup.gz
```

To extract the files from the archive, decompress the gzip file to standard output, piping it to cpio in input mode:

```
zcat /tmp/backup.gz | cpio -i
```

Cpio supports different archive formats, and if you want the output to be compatible across all your platforms, you may want to investigate the different format options.

The GNU version of the tar program has a similar option `-T` (`--files-from=FILE`). You can use a dash (`-`) as the file name to read the file names from standard input.

Comment: i tried but your solution does not work. It creates a gz file but when i extract i get a file instead of the folder structure and its files. See output below:


`[root@myhost moht_bkp]# find /app/jboss -not -name "*.log*" | cpio -o | gzip > /app/moht_bkp/test.gz`

`1360843 blocks`

`[root@myhost moht_bkp]# echo $?
0
`
`[root@myhost moht_bkp]# ls -ltr
total 1097768
-rw-r--r-- 1 root      root      562056007 Jul 20 10:45 test.gz


[root@myhost moht_bkp]# gunzip test.gz
`
`
[root@myhost moht_bkp]# ls -ltr
total 680424
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 696751616 Jul 20 16:34 test`

Comment: @Ashkar The `test` file contains the uncompressed cpio archive. You will have to run cpio in input mode to extract the files. I edited my answer to include instructions for doing that.

Comment: @Ashar you've uncompressed the archive but not extracted any files. You haven't yet done what Johan says to extract the files. If my memory serves, try `cpio -itv <test` to list the archive contents

Comment: The `CPIO` archive format is deprecated since at least 12 years and should not be used  because of known issues. If you like to support many platforms, be careful with problematic implementations found on Linux.In special GNU cpio is still a highly buggy program. How about using `star` since it is highly portable and includes a built in `find` via `libfind`?